# Biblatex-chicago notes sorting same year

Tags: biblatex, sorting, notes, chicago-style

I'm sorry if this has already been answered elsewhere, but I couldn't find it. I would like to get Biblatex-chicago-notes to sort my bibliography when there are several works published the same year by the same author as in Biblatex-chicago-authordate, that is to say add a letter (a, b, c...) after the date/year field. I cannot find out how to do that, and it seems that it does it only in the authordate specification.

Here's a mwe:

```
\documentclass{scrbook}
\usepackage[notes,biber]{biblatex-chicago}
\bibliography{Bibliography}

% @book{Beck:2006pt,
%   Address = {London},
%   Author = {Ulrich Beck},
%   Publisher = {Polity},
%   Title = {Cosmopolitan Vision},
%   Year = {2006}}
%
% @book{Beck:2006kh,
%   Address = {London},
%   Author = {Ulrich Beck},
%   Publisher = {Polity},
%   Title = {Power in the Global Age: A New Global Political Economy},
%   Year = {2006}}

\begin{document}

Blablabla.\autocite{Beck:2006pt} And also blablabla.\autocite{Beck:2006kh}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

I get the result (never mind the ISBN, I'll add the ISBN=false option):
[image: Bibliography]

Comment: Technically, this makes no sense because the `notes` style always prints a long (or quite verbose) version of the citation, whereas the `authordate` version obviously only relies on the date and then appends letters to disambiguate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since `biblatex-chicago` is specifically made to provide CMStyle, the code has to quite some lengths sometimes to comply with the CMS.

With that in mind, remember that you will probably violate the original CMS guidelines by doing this and remember that there might be corner-cases where the solution below does not yield satisfying results - there are quite some places where the style prints a date or year and I'm not entirely sure whether I snooped up all of them, also sometimes the style changes `origdate` and `date` which might lead to problems with the `extrayear` in these cases.

On with the modifications:

First we tell `biblatex` to provide us with the `extrayear` letters by adding the option `labeldate` at loading-time.

We then redefine two macros

```
\renewbibmacro*{cmsyear}{%
  \iftoggle{cms@switchdates}%
    {\printfield{origyear}}%
    {\printfield{year}\printfield{extrayear}}}

\renewbibmacro*{date}{% New for 0.9
  \iftoggle{cms@switchdates}%
    {\printorigdate}%
    {\printdateextra}}
```

In the first we added the `\printfield{extrayear}`, while in the second we replaced `\printdate` by `\printdateextra`.

MWE

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[notes,backend=biber,labeldate]{biblatex-chicago}
\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}

\renewbibmacro*{cmsyear}{%
  \iftoggle{cms@switchdates}%
    {\printfield{origyear}}%
    {\printfield{year}\printfield{extrayear}}}

\renewbibmacro*{date}{% New for 0.9
  \iftoggle{cms@switchdates}%
    {\printorigdate}%
    {\printdateextra}}

\begin{document}
Blablabla.\autocite{knuth:ct:b} And also blablabla.\autocite{knuth:ct:c}

Blablabla.\autocite{knuth:ct:b} And also blablabla.\autocite{knuth:ct:c}

\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: In the MWE you can see why `extrayear` does not make much sense here, in subsequent citations only the title is repeated - the year is not even mentioned.